# Enabling Cookies for Google Calendar Embedded Page in Obsidian Desktop App on Manjaro Linux

Tags: iframe, obsidian

I am attempting to embed the Google Calendar page into my Obsidian note using the `<iframe>` tag on the Obsidian Desktop App. However, I am facing an issue with cookies, and the error message I encounter is as follows:

```
Your browser has cookies disabled. Make sure your cookies are enabled and try again. Learn more
```

Here is the code snippet I am using within my Obsidian note:
`<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

Is there any tag that enables it?

I have verified that cookies are enabled in my browser settings, but the issue persists within the Obsidian Desktop App. My operating system is Manjaro Linux. Has anyone encountered a similar challenge when embedding content with iframes in the Obsidian Desktop App on Linux? Are there specific configurations or workarounds to ensure that cookies are properly enabled for embedded content within Obsidian? Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: As a workaround, did you tried to use some plugin like https://github.com/davish/obsidian-full-calendar to add Google Calendar to Obsidian?

Answer (score 0):

Obsidian does not have access to your browser, it brings its own.

There are some security restrictions that basically disable cookies in iframes, regardless of browser.

The [Custom Frames](https://github.com/Ellpeck/ObsidianCustomFrames) plugin does allow for creating frames with cookies enabled(on desktop, it does not use iframes).

[Source](https://forum.obsidian.md/t/account-log-in-through-iframe-display-complain-cookies-disabled-when-it-is-not/38663)